# get substring between 2 characters in php

Tags: php, string, preg-match, substring

Im using a mentioning system like on twitter and instagram where you simply put @johndoe 
what im trying to do is be able to strip down to the name in-between "@" and these characters `?`,`,`,`]`,`:`,`(space)`

as an example heres my string: 
`hey @johnDoe check out this event, be sure to bring @janeDoe:,@johnnyappleSeed?, @johnCitizen] , and @fredNerk`

how can i get an array of `janeDoe`,`johnnyappleSeed`,`johnCitizen`,`fredNerk` without the characters `?`,`,`,`]`,`:` attached to them.

i know i have to use a variation of `preg_match` but i dont have a strong understanding of it.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/208/

Comment: Some of the components start with "@" and end with ",", not "{space}".

Answer (score 1):

This is what you've asked for: `/\@(.*?)\s/`
This is what you really want: `/\b\@(.*?)\b/`

Put either one into [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and evaluate the results array.

Comment: i updated the question i didnt realize i my question asked for the string till the next (space), i actually want to replace the last character if its a ("]","?","[",":",",") your answer was the closest to what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/\@(.*?)\s/", $string, $result_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$check_hash = preg_match_all ("/@[a-zA-Z0-9]*/g", $string_to_match_against, $matches);
```

You could then do somthing like

```
foreach ($matches as $images){
  echo $images."<br />";
}
```

UPDATE: Just realized you were looking to remove the invalid characters. Updated script should do it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = 'hey @johnDoe check out this event, be sure to bring @janeDoe:,@johnnyappleSeed?, @johnCitizen] , and @fredNerk';
preg_match_all('/@(.*?)(?:[?, \]: ]|$)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @johnDoe
            [1] => @janeDoe:
            [2] => @johnnyappleSeed?
            [3] => @johnCitizen]
            [4] => @fredNerk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => johnDoe
            [1] => janeDoe
            [2] => johnnyappleSeed
            [3] => johnCitizen
            [4] => fredNerk
        )

)
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:@(.*?)(?:[?, \]: ]|$))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  @                        '@'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [?, \]: ]                any character of: '?', ',', ' ', '\]',
                             ':', ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```